About Aristotle and something like "the magic thought"
Some days ago, I was reading secondary sources about Aristotle, it certainly concerned his realism, or moral realism, and read through a line that I vaguely recall going like "Some philosophers label this Aristotle thread of thought as "magical something something".
I have been desperately searching again this document, but I could not find it.
Are there critics about Aristotle philosophy, maybe in particular his realism, that indeed go like this? I.e. that Aristotle philosophy would appear direct and clear, while in reality it avoids complicated question, as by a magic wand.

A's works are not direct and clear at all, but the word "magic" seems off-topic.

@MauroALLEGRANZA By direct and clear I had in mind his realism, which allows to draw clear conclusions about what is morality and what is reality.

@Starckman Possibly to Aristotle is ascribed some magic by later times, see https://www.conimbricenses.org/aristotelianism-and-magic-in-early-modern-europe/ But when reading his main works I do not find any magic.

In philosophy, "magic" tends to mean something like: "not supported by my favorite metaphysics".
If you and I have different metaphysics, then your "logic" becomes my "magic" and vice versa.
I would therefore not pay too much attention to accusations of "magic" thrown at one philosopher by another. It's a form of name calling, most of times.

Or an emotionally laden way of complaining about incomplete or missing data or explanations, throwing shade at the argument rather than the philosopher. Either way, it is really just a declaration that the speaker does not find the argument convincing.

@keshlam Yes, but in a non-charitable manner.

That I agree with. Non-charitable, not necessarily hostile.

@keshlam we're circling perilously close of agreement.
